# How to create Desktop Application with multiple user languages in java?

Tags: java, localization, desktop-application, resourcebundle

I want to create a desktop application in java using Netbeans. I want it to be in both Hindi and English Language. Like in android studio we uses the string.xml which helps us to transalate our application in multiple languages, similar to this what can be used in Netbeans to transalate our Application into other languages.

I have tried this out but I am getting some error..
 This is how my project look like.
[image]

I have tried both

```java
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("hello.hello.bundletest/mybundle");
        String keys = rb.getString("wish");
```

and

```java
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("hello.bundletest/mybundle");
        String keys = rb.getString("wish");
```

mybundle.properties only consist of

```java
wish=Have a nice day
```

Even this is also not working

[image]

Comment: Netbeans is just the IDE, has nothing to do with the application that you build in the end. What technology stack, frameworks do you use and what are *their* localization options!?

Comment: [`ResourceBundle`](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/java-i18n-guide/) is your friend

Comment: I am going to use swing framework with java language @luk2302

Comment: Can you suggest source(s) which start with very basic of ResourceBundle.@g00se

Answer (score 1):

A resource bundle is a .properties file that contains keys and values for specific languages. Using resource bundles allows you to make your code locale-independent.